# Binning Elapsed Minutes between star and end time (same date)

Tags: time, binning

I have a number of start and end times. I assign the fraction of time to 15-minute bins (4 /hr). Each bin would contain 0, 15 or the <15 minutes that would be assigned to that bin. For example, Start 08:42 and end 09:37, would have bins 00:00-08:15 as 0, there would be a value of 12 in bin 08:30, values of 15 in 08:45-9:30, a value of 7 in bin 09:30 and bins 09:45-23:45 would have a value of 0.

arrival <- as.POSIXct(c("2021-03-27 02:41:00", "2021-03-27 05:23:00",
"2021-03-27 05:59:00", "2021-03-27 07:04:00", "2021-03-27 08:10:00"))

depart <- as.POSIXct(c("2021-03-27 08:10:00", "2021-03-27 07:19:00",
"2021-03-27 10:16:00", "2021-03-27 12:08:00", "2021-03-27 15:34:00"))

times <- data.frame(arrival,depart)

The desired output is for each arrival, departure pair, a vector 96 bins of values 0:15.
I can see a way to do this with a for loop, was looking for a more elegant solution.
Any thoughts?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I can see a way to do this with a for loop, was looking for a more elegant solution. Any thoughts?

Often we can use *apply* functions instead of loops, as you certainly know. E. g.:

```
# convert the POSIX times to the minutes of the day
dayminutes = mapply(function (r) (as.numeric(r)/60)%%(60*24), times)
#     arrival depart
#[1,]     161    490
#[2,]     323    439
#[3,]     359    616
#[4,]     424    728
#[5,]     490    934

# use "cut" to divide the ranges arrival:(depart-1) into 15 min. intervals over the day
apply(dayminutes, 1, function(r) as.vector(summary(cut(r['arrival']:(r['depart']-1), 0:(4*24)*15, right=F))))
```

The result is:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0
[11,]    4    0    0    0    0
[12,]   15    0    0    0    0
[13,]   15    0    0    0    0
[14,]   15    0    0    0    0
[15,]   15    0    0    0    0
[16,]   15    0    0    0    0
[17,]   15    0    0    0    0
[18,]   15    0    0    0    0
[19,]   15    0    0    0    0
[20,]   15    0    0    0    0
[21,]   15    0    0    0    0
[22,]   15    7    0    0    0
[23,]   15   15    0    0    0
[24,]   15   15    1    0    0
[25,]   15   15   15    0    0
[26,]   15   15   15    0    0
[27,]   15   15   15    0    0
[28,]   15   15   15    0    0
[29,]   15   15   15   11    0
[30,]   15    4   15   15    0
[31,]   15    0   15   15    0
[32,]   15    0   15   15    0
[33,]   10    0   15   15    5
[34,]    0    0   15   15   15
[35,]    0    0   15   15   15
[36,]    0    0   15   15   15
[37,]    0    0   15   15   15
[38,]    0    0   15   15   15
[39,]    0    0   15   15   15
[40,]    0    0   15   15   15
[41,]    0    0   15   15   15
[42,]    0    0    1   15   15
[43,]    0    0    0   15   15
[44,]    0    0    0   15   15
[45,]    0    0    0   15   15
[46,]    0    0    0   15   15
[47,]    0    0    0   15   15
[48,]    0    0    0   15   15
[49,]    0    0    0    8   15
[50,]    0    0    0    0   15
[51,]    0    0    0    0   15
[52,]    0    0    0    0   15
[53,]    0    0    0    0   15
[54,]    0    0    0    0   15
[55,]    0    0    0    0   15
[56,]    0    0    0    0   15
[57,]    0    0    0    0   15
[58,]    0    0    0    0   15
[59,]    0    0    0    0   15
[60,]    0    0    0    0   15
[61,]    0    0    0    0   15
[62,]    0    0    0    0   15
[63,]    0    0    0    0    4
[64,]    0    0    0    0    0
[65,]    0    0    0    0    0
[66,]    0    0    0    0    0
[67,]    0    0    0    0    0
[68,]    0    0    0    0    0
[69,]    0    0    0    0    0
[70,]    0    0    0    0    0
[71,]    0    0    0    0    0
[72,]    0    0    0    0    0
[73,]    0    0    0    0    0
[74,]    0    0    0    0    0
[75,]    0    0    0    0    0
[76,]    0    0    0    0    0
[77,]    0    0    0    0    0
[78,]    0    0    0    0    0
[79,]    0    0    0    0    0
[80,]    0    0    0    0    0
[81,]    0    0    0    0    0
[82,]    0    0    0    0    0
[83,]    0    0    0    0    0
[84,]    0    0    0    0    0
[85,]    0    0    0    0    0
[86,]    0    0    0    0    0
[87,]    0    0    0    0    0
[88,]    0    0    0    0    0
[89,]    0    0    0    0    0
[90,]    0    0    0    0    0
[91,]    0    0    0    0    0
[92,]    0    0    0    0    0
[93,]    0    0    0    0    0
[94,]    0    0    0    0    0
[95,]    0    0    0    0    0
[96,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Armali, thank you so much. This works exactly as I was hoping.